# What is the meaning of "to say through someone"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this(below) in a chapter named "Silk Road":

He shot me a few questions while feeling the veins in my wrist. "It's a cold," he said finally through Tsetan.

I don't think his soul went into Tsetan and said that.

Comment: Tsetan is the narrator's guide and, no doubt, his translator as well: the doctor spoke in  Tibetan and Tsetan translated his questions and remarks into English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more context, I would assume that Tsetan is an **interpreter**. The person who felt the veins and said "it's a cold" was speaking some language other than that of the narrator, and Tsetan listened, and repeated it in the narrator's own language.

All of this assuming that Tsetan is a person.